# error using the touch function in datomic

Tags: datomic

I read on few sites about the [touch] and how it should be used, but it does not work on my tests. My project.clj uses the following :

```
>    ... 
>         :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
>                        [com.datomic/datomic "0.8.3335"]])
```

My code uses some simple attributes:

```
  :person/fullname string
    :person/pet ref
```

and

```
:pet/name string
:pet/age long
```

In a REPL session I tried:

```
(.touch entity-pet)

IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: touch for class datomic.query.
EntityMap  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

My simple test failed also when I make (in-ns 'pet.core).

What is wrong in my test? Thanks in advance for some hints!!

Answer (score 0):

0.8.3335 is an extremely old release of Datomic, and predates the touch API.  I would recommend trying with the latest release (0.9.4815.12 as I write this).